# Installation of Linux in C drive removing windows and not affecting other drive as well

Tags: system-installation

I use Windows and want to switch to Linux, but I am confused with the installation. I need to install Linux in my C drive removing Windows from it without affecting other drives, how to do it?

Comment: Your system is in BIOS mode or UEFI? Can you attach a Pic of diskmgmt.msc?

Comment: I am using USB installation, after there is a option to erase all data or LVM installation or "something else"

Comment: go back. start from first step and then choose "Try Ubuntu" option.

Comment: First you need to understand where are windows partitions stored in your disk. you may need to delete EFI Partition, MSReserved Partition and C Drive.. in windows "diskmgmt.msc" will give you those details. Can you provide that?

Comment: how to access diskmgmt.msc

Comment: when you are in windows typein run "dismgmt.msc" it will open. if you are already in "try ubuntu" type "GParted" in search and enter

Comment: https://we.tl/actxfP9Mtm here is the pic if you are in "try ubuntu" option and then open GParted.

Comment: I can recognize my c drive as 100gb drive others are more than that.

Comment: https://we.tl/M04tnsRY7f here is the diskmgmt.msc pic. any way since you can recognize your c drive.. lets start with "try ubuntu" option. can you go to GParted and send me the pic as https://we.tl/actxfP9Mtm. to understand further

Comment: yes! I got it the what's next!

Comment: https://we.tl/TGIjo2veR8

Comment: I won't be able to use internet when I will be in try ubuntu mode so, please explain here only!

Comment: I have gone through the pic. thanks. you have to go with "try ubuntu" option. and then open "GParted" and Delete 450MB, 100MB, C 98.96GB and 501MB partitions. after that you have to go click  "Install Ubuntu" option and then first create a EFI Partition of around 500mb and remaining space with ext4 mounted to / (back slash) and then install now.

Comment: from "try ubuntu" option you can connect to internet as in normal systems.

Comment: Do I need to create separate partition of EFI Partition(500mb) and remaining space, and how to do  ext4 mounted to / (back slash)

Comment: Yes you have to create seperate partition of EFI Partition. the way you selectd "EFI Partition" in something else screen.. you can select ext4 partition also..once you select it, it will allow you to mount it to and gives options..there you can select / (back slash) EFI Partition and Back Slash are mandatory...without these you can not install Ubuntu.

Comment: ok, wait i am starting to do it, will send you pics for further process in minutes

Answer (score 0):

Start from your USB thumb drive. Use the Try Ubuntu option as suggested before. After the full start you might want to make sure you are connected to the Internet first. You are going to need it for the installation. Next start the installation process.

This should be fairly self-explanatory up to the point where Ubuntu offers you to erase everything else and install it alone and like 3 other options. You will find an option ("Something else"?) that gives you the option to manually address the issue at hand. Usually the last one at the bottom. This option will take you to the list of harddisks and partitions.

WARNING: if you mess this up, you can lose your data.

But in this dialog you can make individual settings, as far as the harddrive goes. So, find your C partition. Mostly likely (BUT NOT GUARANTEED) /dev/sda1. Identified correctly, now tell it to put the mount point root or "/" there. And that will put the root file system there and install Linux on your C partion. Of course the C partition is going to be formatted and all former data will be gone, since Linux will use it's own, not a Windows file system.

Also make sure the boot manager is installed in the proper place.

If you use more than one operating system, make sure they are all either set up to use BIOS OR UEFI mode to start. Don't mix them.

If Windows was on your C partition before and given there is enough space on partition C, if everything is done properly, Windows (and everything else you had on your partition C before) will be gone and Linux is going to run from it.

Comment: BTW ... in regards to the former comments: no it is actually NOT necessary to create a separate 500MB partition, although it is common practice. Also it doesn't make much sense, if you don't put your /boot mount point there. And BTW in Linux it is SLASH (not backslash). Also you might be interested to know, that Ubuntu likes to clutter up the boot partition and therefore cause problems. So, IF you create a 500MB partition for boot, as suggested before, make sure you keep it clean in the long run.